# Differentiation a cubic matrix term

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I would like to differentiate this matrix A with respect to a vector x: 
$$A = x^tBxy^tx$$

where B is a known matrix. y is a vector with the same dimension with x. I tried to google but only found the result for quadratic form, not cubic like this

Answer (score 2):

The quantity in question is a scalar, not a matrix.

Let's find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\alpha &= x^TBxy^Tx \cr&= Bxy^T:xx^T \cr
d\alpha
 &= Bxy^T:d(xx^T) + B\,dx\,y^T:xx^T \cr
 &= Bxy^T:(dx\,x^T+x\,dx^T) + xx^T:B\,dx\,y^T \cr
 &= (Bxy^Tx+yx^TB^Tx + B^Txx^Ty):dx \cr
\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x}
 &= Bxy^Tx+yx^TB^Tx + B^Txx^Ty \cr
}$$
where a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product
$$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
And the cyclic properties of the trace allow for a number of ways to rearrange the terms in the product. For example, all of the following products are equal
$$\eqalign{
A:BC
 &= BC:A \cr
 &= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
 &= B^TA:C \cr
 &= AC^T:B \cr
 &= etc \cr
}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can notice that you can separate your product into two scalars $A = (x^TBx)(y^Tx)$. 
$$
  \nabla_x A = \left[\nabla_x(x^TBx)\right](y^Tx) + (x^TBx)\left[\nabla_x (y^Tx)\right] =
y^Tx(B+B^T)x + x^TBxy.
$$

If you are aware of tensor notation, it is straightforward:
$$
A_{,i} = \partial_i\left(x_jB_{jk}x_ky_lx_l\right) = B_{jk}y_l \ \partial_i\left(x_jx_kx_l\right) = B_{jk}y_l\left(x_{j,i}x_kx_l+x_{j}x_{k,i}x_l+x_{j}x_kx_{l,i}\right) = \\
B_{jk}y_l\left(\delta_{ji}x_kx_l+x_{j}\delta_{ki}x_l+x_{j}x_k\delta_{li}\right)=(B_{ik}+B_{ki})x_ky_lx_l+B_{jk}x_jx_ky_i
$$

Comment: Funny, when I looked at the problem I immediately saw a matrix being contracted with two vectors, when you looked at it you saw the product of two scalars. It all depends on where you put those mental parentheses. $$(x^TBx)(y^Tx)=x^T(Bxy^T)x$$